# org-mode Add property column to the org agenda clock report

Tags: org-mode

In a standard `org-agenda` with `clockreport` mode, how can I add a column to show a specific custom property? Each (level 2) headline has a property :JOBNO: that I would like to show as follows:

```
| File  | JOBNO | Headline             | Time   |      |
|-------+-------+----------------------+--------+------|
|       |       | ALL *Total time*     | *1:04* |      |
|-------+-------+----------------------+--------+------|
| T.org |       | *File time*          | *1:04* |      |
|       |       | Dept 1               | 0:13   |      |
|       | P100  | \_  Project 1a       |        | 0:13 |
|       |       | Dept 2               | 0:51   |      |
|       | P200  | \_  Project 2b ]     |        | 0:51 |
```

I've tried setting org-overriding-columns-format and org-columns-default-format-for-agenda nothing changes - but the ``clockreport`is not a columns view as such. I had this working before and lost my .emacs file in a move!